# How to replace value in list based on word behind it and replace it by number generated from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fix some of my generated sentence, by turning back some of the pre-processing i have done.

`Generated_sentence = "Had to wait @ minutes for the pizza"`

I want to change the @ sign back into a number. I have created a dataframe containing information about the median value and standard deviation of the numbers before the word minutes in the original dataset. I have also done this for some other word.

This is part of this dataframe

```
| word| median| std|
|---- |------| -----|
| minutes| 20| 20|
|pm|9|2|
|stars|3|2|
```

Now i want to change the @ back based on the word behind it so in this case that is minutes and then i want to generate a number based on the median value and the standard deviation. How do i do that?

Comment: In your example, what do you want to replace `@` with?

Comment: A number generated around the median(20) with a standard deviation of 20, so for example it could just be replaced by 20. But it does need to be a rounded number, not 21.232, but 21 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking:

```py
Generated_sentence = "Had to wait @ minutes for the pizza"
words = [x.strip() for x in Generated_sentence.split()]
word = words[words.index('@') + 1]
sentence = Generated_sentence.replace('@', str(round(df.loc[df['word'] == word, 'median'].tolist()[0])))
```

Input

```
      word  median  std
0  minutes    20.5   20
1       pm     9.0    2
2    stars     3.0    2
```

Output

```
Had to wait 20 minutes for the pizza
```